# Processing multiline html textarea in c#

Tags: c#, html, textarea, multiline

I have a textarea on my html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#btnSquareNumbers").click(function () {
                    var Calculate = $("#txtString").val();
                    //Calculate = $("#txtString") //.Replace("<br/>", ",").TrimEnd(',')
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/api/SquareNumbers/SquareNums/",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: JSON.stringify(Calculate),
                        success: function (result) {
                            $("#txtResult").val(result);
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                            $("#txtResult").val(err.Message)
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="txtString" cols=50 rows="15"></textarea><br>
    <input type="button" value="Square All Numbers" id="btnSquareNumbers"><br>
    <output type="text" id="txtResult" disabled />
</body>
</html>
```

It will accept a vertical list of numbers e.g.

- 2
- 5
- 8
- 13

I need to send this to the C# controller, square each number and display the results on the web page.
When I run the code, it truncates the numbers and gives 25813 squared!
I am new to this... any advice?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
namespace ReturnMultilineText.Controllers
{
    public class SquareNumbersController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public List<int> SquareNums([FromBody]string Calculate)
        {
            List<string> caseList = txtString.Split().ToList();
            List<int> intList = caseList.ConvertAll(int.Parse);
            List<int> ans = new List<int>();

            for (var i = 0; i < intList.Count; i++)
            {
                ans.Add((intList[i] * intList[i]));
            }

            return ans;
        }
    }
}
```

Input:
1 2 3 4
2 3 4
Gives Output:
1,4,9,16,1,4,9

I am nearly there now.... Need to find the linefeed... does stringify remove it? and replace it with a space?

GOT THE SOLUTION... just needed to split by "\n"...

```
string[] textList = Calculate.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Cheers for the help and advice.

Comment: How are you sending the data? Make a json object and send that.

Comment: Also post your form code and the code on the back end controller that processes it. It is likely that the solution will be some variation based on what @SamMarion suggested, which would use javascript to post your form and format the input data in an array instead of a string, which is likely what is happening if you are not submitting with js.

Comment: Cheers Sam... I am fairly new to this stuff. I think I was sending it as a text string using ajax. I just found a page on jQuery - AJAX get() and post() Methods... I am going to study those. Ill look at json too...

Comment: I think you may have two options: the first being splitting the form data into an array in javascript before sending to the c# controller, and the other, if your data is submitted as a delimited string of any kind, you can use String.Split to break each number up and convert the textinput to an array, which you can then loop over and perform your operations on. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/how-to-parse-strings-using-string-split)

In order to use String.Split the controller must be able to detect a specific delimiter in your form data.

Comment: I have updated the question to include all code... Thanks for the help...